# How many point-tangent pairs determine a super ellipse of degree $d$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, plane-geometry

I am seeking theory that would help answer these questions.

> How many pairs of curve points and tangents at those points
>   (*point-tangent pairs*) determine an ellipse?
>   How many point-tangent pairs determine a super ellipse of degree $d$?
>   How many point-tangent pairs determine a closed convex curve $C$
>   defined as the zero-set of a 
>   specific polynomial of degree $d$?

For example, If $C$ is a circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$,
then one point $p$ and tangent vector $t$ at $p$ do not suffice, because
$C$ could lie on either side of that tangent at $p$.
But two (distinct) point-tangents
suffice to pinpoint the circle's location.

---

[image: SuperEllipse4]

          

<sup>Super ellipse $x^4/2 + y^4 = 1$, rotated.</sup>

---

In a sense, I am seeking variants of [the theorem that $5$ points determine
a conic section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic), but in my case, I have point-tangent pairs.
I am expecting that the number of point-tangent pairs needed
increases with $d$.

Comment: The linear-algebraic part of this is very simple: just as $k$ points impose $k$ conditions on polynomials of any degree, so $k$ points and $k$ tangent vectors impose $2k$ conditions. The tricky bit is trying to understand whether non-proportional polynomials really give different curves. I am not sure about this just yet,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just like in the case of [conic sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), take $x^n+y^n=r^n$, and apply a $2D$ rotation and a $2D$ translation to it, so as to obtain the most general formula possible. How many terms or coefficients does it possess ? In the case of [quadratics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), we had $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey=F,$$ implying $5$ unknowns for any given *F*. Here, the role of *F* is played by $r^n$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear.